# Can operating system work without kernel?

Tags: kernel

Is operating system and kernel one and the same?  I have a doubt about the difference between both of them.

Comment: That sounds like they were trying to make an interesting point. Please add a link to that pdf.

Comment: This is not about Unices nor Linux.

Comment: Can auto may work without _engine_? No, because any device which makes auto moving will be called _engine_. Same works for _kernel_, its just a word to describe OS core functional block, even though it can be very small (such as microkernel).

Comment: Dos, cp/m, ≤ macos 9, ≤ MS-Windows me (but not NT), Amiga OS, … These did not have a separate kernel, or processes (though some had tasks): Everything shared the same memory space.

Comment: To thank me, press the little up arrow to the left of the comment.

Comment: There are also (in research at least), some modern operating systems, that have no physical (with hardware support) processes. Instead they use co-operating tasks (so far no different to the bad old days), but when the operating system loads one of these tasks, it first proves that it will behave. To do this the program must be written in a suitable language, and the compiler must export additional information to help the proof engine. This can result in a faster system, that can run on cheaper hardware (no MMU).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What we call the `kernel` is the operating system's low level functionality.

On most operating system designs, there is a core component to do that job, even if named differently.

While it is possible to boot to a single process which would take care of everything on its own, it would still be the highest ranked process, not just a regular soldier (kernel analogy).

Comment: [The kernel metaphor is something else](http://superuser.com/a/329479/38062).  A _kernel_ is not a _colonel_.

Comment: I think Kernel comes from nuts (they also have a shell).